# when create docker-compose up give me permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed docker desktop on mac, when run

```
docker-compuse up
```

return this error
`open /Users/enad/.docker/buildx/current: permission denied`

I am trying to add permission

Comment: Is your user a member of the "docker" group?

Comment: How to create user group on mac

Comment: Try the following commande : "docker compose up"

Comment: when run docker compose up it is the same